# В переменную закинуть результат запроса

Tags: mysql

MySQL 5.1. Есть ли возможность переменной [[[@a](/users/106/andreycha)](/users/106/andreycha)](/users/106/andreycha) присвоить результат запроса без вызова:

```
SELECT @a:=price FROM reserve WHERE id=1;
```

а если вот так:

```
SET @a=`SELECT price FROM reserve WHERE id=1;
```

то выдаёт ошибку!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Если "без вызова" подразумевает - не возвращать результат SELECT-а, то:

```
SELECT price FROM reserve WHERE id=1 INTO @a;
```

Comment: спасибо KiTE за помощь!! прост триггер пишу а он SELECT-ы не хочет выполнять, ща все получилось

Comment: Пожалуйста